# R st_centroid GEOS error Unknown WKB type 12

Tags: r, sf, centroids

I’m trying to calculate centroids of polygons of postcode areas (wfs shapefile), but I’m getting the following error message:

```
Error in CPL_geos_op(“centroid”, x, numeric(0), integer(0), numeric(0), : Evaluation error: ParseException: Unknown WKB type 12.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have no idea what this means. I assume there is something unusual with the formatting of the geometry column(?).

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ows4R_0.1-5     geometa_0.6-3   forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.5    
 [6] purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.0    ggplot2_3.3.3  
[11] tidyverse_1.3.0 httr_1.4.2      sf_0.9-7        sp_1.4-5        RPostgres_1.3.1
```

Reproducible example (get data from WFS server)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(httr)
library(ows4R)

# get postcode data ####

# following info from
# https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_wfs_services/

# connect to Statistics Finland geoserver ####
wfs_regions <- "http://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/postialue/wfs"
regions_client <- WFSClient$new(wfs_regions, 
                                serviceVersion = "2.0.0")
regions_client$getFeatureTypes(pretty = TRUE)

url <- parse_url(wfs_regions)
url$query <- list(service = "wfs",
                  request = "GetFeature",
                  typename = "postialue:pno_2018",
                  srsName = "EPSG:3067"
                  )

request <- build_url(url)

# grab data ####
postal_codes <- read_sf(request)
# st_geometry(postal_codes)

ggplot(postal_codes) +
  geom_sf()

# subset to smaller area, e.g. #### 
pc.helsinki <- postal_codes[postal_codes$kunta == "091",]

ggplot(pc.helsinki) +
  geom_sf()

# centroids of postcode polygons ####
pc.helsinki$centroid <- st_centroid(pc.helsinki$geom)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To handle the conversion mentioned by @user30184 within R, you can use the `ogr2ogr()` function provided by my [**gdalUtilities**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdalUtilities/index.html) package.

To demonstrate its use, here is a little utility function adapted from one I've used in the past when needing to convert `MULTISURFACE` geometries to `MULTIPOLYGON` geometries.

```r
library(gdalUtilities)

ensure_multipolygons <- function(X) {
    tmp1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".gpkg")
    tmp2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".gpkg")
    st_write(X, tmp1)
    ogr2ogr(tmp1, tmp2, f = "GPKG", nlt = "MULTIPOLYGON")
    Y <- st_read(tmp2)
    st_sf(st_drop_geometry(X), geom = st_geometry(Y))
}

## Try it on your data
pc.helsinki_2 <- ensure_multipolygons(pc.helsinki)
pc.helsinki_2_centroids <- st_centroid(pc.helsinki_2)
```

If you'd like to ensure that each of the "centroids" will lie somewhere within the `MULTIPOLYGON` from which it's derived, you can instead use `st_point_on_surface()`, like this:

```r
ggplot(pc.helsinki_2) +
    geom_sf() +
    geom_sf(data = st_point_on_surface(pc.helsinki_2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The WKB type 12 means MultiSurface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry.

And indeed that server returns MultiSurface geometries

http://geo.stat.fi/geoserver/postialue/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=postialue:pno_2018&srsName=EPSG:3067&count=2

The geometries are not really curved ones because inside MultiSurface there are just linear rings

```
<gml:MultiSurface srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#3067" srsDimension="2">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
...
```

Anyway, your software seems to think that it does not know how to handle curved geometries and therefore it does not even have a try with these data.

I suggest to save the data on disk as XML by using the URL above but without `&count=2` limit. Then you can use ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html and convert data into some format that your software can read with an option `-nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR`. I believe that your software can open that converted dataset.

Comment: thanks @user30184, I'll have a look if I can sort this out via QGIS first (i.e. save to shapefile)