# The combination of sf::st_union and sf::st_transform turns a valid geometry into an invalid one

Tags: r, sf

Consider the simple feature `MULTIPOLYGON` with 2 features:

```
> library(sf)
> x
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 6 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 707235.3 ymin: 4612121 xmax: 721998.4 ymax: 4623036
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  ID_POLYGON                           SIOSE_CODE                                               SUPERF_HA CODIIGE HILUCS CODBLQ                                                  geom
  <chr>                                <chr>                                                        <dbl>   <int>  <int> <chr>                                     <MULTIPOLYGON [m]>
1 7da25da1-c28b-4d91-8fa0-b0b735691310 I(45A(35CNF_35MTR_25PST_05FDP)_35A(55PST_45MTR)_20CHLsc)      540.     260    631 02     (((720215.4 4613902, 720253.7 4613771, 720203.1 4613~
2 4D4E8C04-39DD-B044-9F05-9F41000D5973 A(45CNF_35MTR_15PST_05FDP)                                   2391.     312    631 02     (((708017 4622925, 708085.4 4622904, 708164.3 462293~
```

with **valid geometry** in both cases

```
> st_is_valid(x)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

If I transform `x`, geometry is still valid

```
> st_transform(x, crs = "EPSG:3035") |> st_is_valid()
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

If I union both features, the geometry is still valid

```
> st_union(x) |> st_is_valid()
[1] TRUE
```

But if I transform the feature after the union, **geometry is invalid**

```
> st_union(x) |> st_transform(crs = "EPSG:3035") |> st_is_valid()
[1] FALSE
```

Making the invalid geometry valid, returns a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, composed of a `POLYGON` and a `LINESTRING`

```
> st_union(x) |> st_transform(crs = "EPSG:3035") |> st_make_valid()
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 3446458 ymin: 2117739 xmax: 3459519 ymax: 2130833
Projected CRS: ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON ((3457963 2119600, ...
```

I have notice, however, that reversing the order of the operations, transforming first and doing the union later, keeps the validity of the geometry

```
> st_transform(x, crs = "EPSG:3035") |> st_union() |> st_is_valid()
[1] TRUE
```

It is not clear to me what is the problem with transforming after the union.

Comment: Please add the source geometries as WKT.

Comment: I would like to get a complete WKT geometries that could be studied with other programs with copy-paste. Like `MULTIPOLYGON ((( -39 15, -38 13, -39 12, -39 15 )), (( -38 15, -36 15, -37 13, -38 15 )))`

Comment: Se second geometry is too long to be pasted, but you can download the data and the posted code [here](https://consigna.uv.es/consigna/pub/Consigna?recoge:es:0_1442_2266_3512). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I saved your data info PostGIS and it returns TRUE with `select st_isvalid(st_transform(st_union("GEOMETRY"),3035)) from polygon`. Perhaps your issue is somehow r-specific. Also the geometry that PostGIS creates is a polygon.

Comment: it's getting a little sliver hole in the polygon, do this to see it https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/241b50d6498c461de82680d426ef4162

Comment: @mdsumner: This is great - learned sth new again, thanks! - but why is the order of execution important here?

Comment: Many thanks @mdsummer! This explains the `LINESTRING` in the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, but as @dmflk mentions is no clear why we don´t get the problem changing the order of the operations. Maybe is a consecuence of not setting precission.

Comment: yes maybe precision ... I really don't know but I'm interested to explore more - I *think* the sliver is a fragment of the boundary between the original polys? so, it's like a part of their intersection is kept

Comment: The original polygons (from the National Mapping Aggency) are geometry type `CURVEPOLYGON`, that I transform to `MULTIPOLYGON` using  the `ensure multipolygons` funcion found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389814/r-st-centroid-geos-error-unknown-wkb-type-12), and then dissolved and re-proyected. Original polygons are [here](https://consigna.uv.es/consigna/pub/Consigna?recoge:es:9348_5914_7719_2272). From a practical point of view I do the transformation first, and the union later, since this avoids the problem.